# Tokbox failed to create session

Tags: meteor, opentok, tokbox

```
[Error: Failed to createSession. Error: An authentication error
occurred: (403) {"code":-1,"message":"Expired token"}]
```

I was able to create a session just fine on my localhost server, but when
I put it in production - which has https - the error occurs.

I am using tokbox with Meteor framework and wraping the function inside a method:

```
const opentok = new OpenTok(Meteor.settings.public.opentok.apiKey, Meteor.settings.public.opentok.apiSecret);

let createSessionSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(opentok.createSession, opentok);
```

Comment: Did you check if you are getting the right `apiKey` and `apiSecret` on production environment?

Comment: @bennygenel yes it the apikey and apiSecret was correct

Comment: this looks like a tokbox error. can you add a callback to createSession `opentok.createSession(function(err, session) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);

  // save the sessionId
  console.log('session', session.sessionId);
});`. Maybe error message would help to solve the problem.

Comment: The error suggests the token is not valid anymore. Have you tried creating a new fresh token?

Comment: the error message that return is the token error message weirdly i just reboot my server and everything is back to normal.  i haven't create any token yet and it said token error it is very weird

Comment: When you make the API call to create a session a JSON Web Token is generated which has an encoded expiration time. My guess is that the system time on your production server was off and so it was generating tokens that had already expired. Then restarting the server re-sync'd the clock and you didn't have the issue anymore.

Comment: i see that make sense

Answer (score 1):

Rebooting our local development servers did not fix the problem for us when we ran into this issue. It appeared the developer was changing timezone settings on their machine and the system clocks got out of sync with the development server somehow (though the timezone was set to his local time at the moment) but later we realized Docker desktop was creating containers with the wrong date and time. This supports the comment by @Adam Ullman above.

Initially, we solved this by changing the timezone in the Windows system settings. At this point the error went away without restarting the servers. However, see update below:

## UPDATE:

The developer ran into the same issue again and timezone changing did not fix it this time. We realized that the Docker container was being created with the wrong time settings (We determined this by logging out the current time in the container). The date in the docker container was a day and several hours behind the computer's time.

It is important to note that deleting the images and restarting the containers alone did not solve the issue. Also, we found that other JWT tokens in the application were also affected not just opentok's.

To solve this, we had to stop Docker Desktop and restart it. This resynchronized all newly created container times to the Windows machine time.

Answer (score 0):

reboot the server seem to work but i just don't know why create session is related to token error since i haven't even use the token yet

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error just because the machine time had an error of 1 minute. When I synced to the correct time, the error immediately stopped.